# Python code error 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having trouble compiling this program.

I am new to python.I am using python 2.7.(Anaconda)

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as numpy
import scipy
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
def getwavdata(file):
 return scipy.io.wavfile.read(file)[1]
data=getwavdata('myvoice.wav')
print data
frameDuration = 0.01

frequency          = 44100 
numSamplesPerFrame = int(frequency * frameDuration)
frameSize=int(frequency*frameDuration)
signalEnergy=sum( [ abs(x)**2 for x in data ] )
print 'signal energy',signalEnergy
threshold=signalEnergy/3
print threshold
 base=0
i=0
  count=0
 wordNumber=0
 length=len(data)
  print 'length of data is', length
 word=[]
while i<length:
    #print 'entered while loop'
        frame=data[base:frameSize]
    base=base+frameSize
    frameEnergy=sum( [ abs(x)**2 for x in frame ] ) 
    if frameEnergy < threshold:
        count=count+1
        word.append(frame)
        word=numpy.array(word)
    else :
        count=0
        word=[]
     if count == 4:
        print 'silence expected'
        wordNumber=wordNumber+1
        scipy.io.wavfile.write('word%d.wav' %wordNumber,44100,word)
        count=0
        word=[]
      i = i+1
```

Now the problem is **when I first ran this program,it printed some expected values.**

It printed **signalEnergy=some value around 3000000** and **threshold=some value around 1000000(1/3 of signalEnergy)** ,but with an error here:

```
scipy.io.wavfile.write('word%d.wav' %wordNumber,44100,word)
```

**error:list has no attribute array(something like that.Dont remember the exact sentence)**

I googled and found that write() takes an array as one argument.

Trying to fix that error has resulted in the whole program not working.

**Now for signalEnergy and threshold,I am getting an array of two values,instead of a single value.**

The changes I made:

```
while (base+frameSize)<length:
    #print 'entered while loop'
    frame=data[base:base+frameSize]
    frameEnergy=sum( [ abs(x)**2 for x in frame ] ) 
    print frameEnergy
    if frameEnergy.all() < threshold.all():
        count=count+1
        word.append(frame)
    else:
        count=0
        word=[]
    if count == 4:
        print 'word detected'
        wordNumber=wordNumber+1
        word = numpy.array(word)  
        scipy.io.wavfile.write('word'+str(wordNumber)+'.wav',44100,word)
        count=0
        word=[]
    base = base + frameSize

Error:

[-29501  24682](**this is what it is giving as signalEnergy now**)


[-9834  8227]


length of data is 122240
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Nancy Semwal\Documents\Python Scripts\program2.py",     line 34, in <module>


 if frameEnergy < threshold:


ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I understand the error,but what I am unable to get is that why it ran correctly for the first time?

What could be the reason?What changes shall I make?

Comment: How much of the code is relevant to the question? Remove everything which doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to read your code and understand the exact errors you are getting but I can see a few obvious errors that might move you along:

1. In your first code, the slice of the list:

   ```
    frame=data[base:frameSize]
   ```

   will stop working once you run through the loop frameSize time. Since you are never increasing your upper bound. Basically slicing is:

   ```
    myList[included_bottom_bound:excluded_top_bound]
   ```

   You seem to have fixed that in your second go-round though with

   ```
    frame=data[base:base+frameSize]
   ```

   although I'm not 100% sure what your intent is. It looks like you are looking through a sound file for low volume pieces. The first time through you are walking 1 step ahead each time and looking at the next chunk of data, while the 2nd time through you look at a chunk and then move a whole chunk sized step ahead. Imagine that the sound file looked like this:

   ```
    *--*
   ```

   where * (star) means high volume and - (dash) means low volume. Imagine your frameSize was 2. Stepping 1 step at a time (as in attempt 1) you'd have 4 samples

   1. *-
   2. --
   3. -*
   4. *

   and you'd discover the low volume section in (item #2 above).
   With your new way of doing things you'd end up with 2 samples only

   1. *-
   2. -*

   and end up missing the low volume section you're hunting for.
2. What's the deal with the line:

   ```
    if frameEnergy.all() < threshold.all():
   ```

   frameEnergy is a sum so it's going to be an int or a long or something numeric at least. You can't do a all() on something like that. Same deal with threshold.

Looking at your comments it seems like signalEnergy is now not some simple number? That seems weird. Maybe you should put some more print statements into your code and find out why. 
I downloaded a sample wav file and ran your code against it and it worked and printed a bunch of wordX.wav files. They didn't play mind you but the code worked. I fixed the whitespace problems and such but.... Here's my final code:

```
<pre><code>import numpy as numpy
import scipy
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
def getwavdata(file):
    return scipy.io.wavfile.read(file)[1]
data=getwavdata('E:\\Music\\Sounds\\carlin_letter.wav')
print data
frameDuration = 0.01

frequency          = 44100 
numSamplesPerFrame = int(frequency * frameDuration)
frameSize=int(frequency*frameDuration)
signalEnergy=sum( [ abs(x)**2 for x in data ] )
print 'signal energy',signalEnergy
threshold=signalEnergy/3
print threshold
base=0
i=0
count=0
wordNumber=0
length=len(data)
print 'length of data is', length
word=[]
while (base+frameSize)&lt;length:
    #print 'entered while loop'
    frame=data[base:base+frameSize]
    frameEnergy=sum( [ abs(x)**2 for x in frame ] ) 
    print frameEnergy
    if frameEnergy &lt; threshold:
        count=count+1
        word.append(frame)
    else:
        count=0
        word=[]
    if count == 4:
        print 'word detected'
        wordNumber=wordNumber+1
        word = numpy.array(word)  
        scipy.io.wavfile.write('e:\\music\\sounds\\word'+str(wordNumber)+'.wav',44100,word)
        count=0
        word=[]
    base = base + frameSize
print "done"</code></pre>
```

Comment: yeah..that's what I am unable to understand.I did that threshold.all() thing after reading the error.SignalEnergy and Threshold are supposed to besingle values,god knows why the program is giving a 2 element array in place of a single value for them.

Comment: Also,sorry for the terrible formatting and lengthy code..I'm new to StackOverflow..so will learn to write better questions.